# How the application knows if the file has been opened on double click in windows?

Tags: windows, file

To be more specific, say application A will open the file of type `.typ`.
In windows if I double click any file of `.typ` extension the application gets launched and the file gets opened. My question is:

1. what OS does on double click, and what command does OS send to application to open the file
2. How does the application different between normal file open and file open using double click?

Comment: In general configured [File Associations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd758090(v=vs.85).aspx) cause the invoked file name to be passed to the associated executable as a command line argument.

Comment: What is your programming problem? Are trying to reimplement what the OS does?

Comment: @Alex : thanks for the information . Raymond: We want to do some action differently depending on whether the file is open on double click or by normal file open dialog . Currently we are using some kind of timer mechanism to fix this problem , but that does not look feasible and has some performance impact also .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When file is open within an app it is well coded as a standalone activity.

When you double click a file from a specific type the OS look at the registry to see what executable should be used to open it. For example :
`.txt` file (text file - by default opened with notepad)
main file association in the registry will be at `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt`
the default key in it will direct to `txtfile` key
and his turn will instruct the OS to execute the command described here `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\shell\open\command`
the execution instruction is `%SystemRoot%\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE %1`
mean: execute `notepad.exe` from your `Windows\system32` and pass the file name whove you just double click to it as `%1`.